# Need to Generate random value to respective textbox divided by 5 in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to generate random value after selecting dropdown,
If I select **Normal** then value should be between 10 to 30 which is divided by 5,
If I select **AbNormal** then value should be between 35 to 60 which is divided by 5.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0X2O.png)

After using below code, same value is reflecting in all textbox

```
public string RandomNumber1(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random1 = new Random();
        return Convert.ToString(random1.Next(min, max));
    }
```

Comment: "After using below code, same value is reflecting in all textbox" -> https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Random

Comment: Can you show the calling code? What are you doing with the returned value?

Comment: Random class has a default state on which Next method depends. In your code you creating it every time, and because of that it starts form the same default state.

Comment: Please refer to official documentation on expected usage:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#instantiating-the-random-number-generator

Comment: @NicklausBrain - not *exactly*, but the idea goes in the right direction. A `new Random()` instance is seeded with the tick value of the current timestamp. But that value is only updated in bigger increments (every 100-150 "real" ticks on my machine for example). So creating lots of instances in a tight loop will get the same seed and thus the same sequence of (pseudo) random values. As mentioned, https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Random explains it much better.

Comment: The (single thread) solution: create **one** static instance of `Random` outside the method and re-use it. (The multi-thread solution is a bit more involved)

Comment: @Corak, you're right! While I do believe that behavior I described was correct somewhere before. Although in .core 2.2 Random surely uses ticks instead of predefined seed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Very much guys for quick respose, 
I achieve my result on following way

```
 Random rng = new Random();
 txtR500.Text = GenerateDigit(rng, 40, 65).ToString();

 static int GenerateDigit(Random rng, int min, int max)
    {
        // Assume there'd be more logic here really
        int i=rng.Next(min, max);
        for (int j = min; j < max; )
        {
            if ((i % 5 == 0) || (i % 5 == 5))
            {
                return i;
            }
            else
            { i++; }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```